# Listview with imagebutton bad work

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-imagebutton

I have Like button in each row of listview,
when click them, they change color to red!

When I click imagebutton in a row AND I scroll down the listview, in addition to clicked imagebutton, the other imagebutton also change color
WHY ????

```
public override View GetView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {

            var  item = (Tips)this.GetItem(position);
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
            {
                view = this.activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_item_Tips, null);
            }
            var TextTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titletxt);
            TextTitle.Text = item.TITLE;

            var TextWriter = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contenttxt);
            TextContent.Text = item.CONTENT;;


            view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                    view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_liked);

                    item.LIKE = true;
                    item.LIKE_COUNT++;

                    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.like_count).Text = item.LIKE_COUNT.ToString();
                }
            };

            return view;
        }
```

Link bug pictures:

[Clicked Img](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04mXSBqSxbrWGtsVHpRYmdrdzg&authuser=0)

[Scrolled Down Img](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04mXSBqSxbrVDh4cnlUMWxQbE0&authuser=0)

Comment: try calling xamarin method for notifyDataSetChanged() in your ImageButton Click method

Comment: @chiragjn thank you, but this method for insert and delete and etc row.

Comment: added an answer that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arises because of View row is not recycled properly and so referring to the wrong view row. Use the viewholder class to declare all the control and tag the instance of this class to each row.

For Ex:

```
public override  View GetView (int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent)
{ 
      View rowView = convertView;
 //reuse view
 if (rowView == null) { 
  rowView = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ItemCustomLayout, parent, false); 

  viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem ();
  viewHolder.txtTemName = rowView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblItemName);
  rowView.Tag = viewHolder; //attaching viewholder reference to row
 } 
 else
 {
  viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem)rowView.Tag; //during row re-use get the instance of the view holder
 } 
       viewHolder.txtTemName.Text = strX; 
 return rowView;
}
```

//view holder class

```
class ViewHolderItem :Java.Lang.Object
        {
         internal   TextView txtTemName; 
        }
```

Find more details here : http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/07/working-on-issues-with-listview-in.html#ViewHolderTag

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon you mentioned happens because listview items are recycled, to ensure correct behavior, after obtaining the view object check whether the item.LIKE is true, If it is true , change color, else show the normal color

```
public override View GetView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {

        var  item = (Tips)this.GetItem(position);
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = this.activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_item_Tips, null);
        }
        var TextTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.titletxt);
        TextTitle.Text = item.TITLE;

        var TextWriter = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.contenttxt);
        TextContent.Text = item.CONTENT;;

        if(item.LIKE)
        {
            view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_liked);
        }
        else
        {
            view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_normal);
        }

        view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
                view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Like).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_liked);

                item.LIKE = true;
                item.LIKE_COUNT++;

                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.like_count).Text = item.LIKE_COUNT.ToString();
                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        return view;
    }
```

Code might not be correct , I am not familiar with Xamarin syntax